# Adding points to a mesh

Tags: c++, 3d, point-cloud-library, cgal

I have a point source that continuously streams points.  I would like to build a mesh/surface of the ground plane that I detect in these points (and then stream out the ground points.)

Right now I use PCL's [ProgressiveMorphologicalFilter](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/progressive_morphological_filtering.php) filter to separate the ground from every package of points I get, but this still returns the data in a `PointCloud`.

There are PCL functions to build a surface, but they're slow.  So ideally I would like to iteratively build the surface, i.e. build a surface from the first X points, then extend the surface with the next X points, etc. This way I'm never building a surface from a huge cloud, but instead building up a surface from many little clouds.

I can't seem to find any PCL or CGAL functions that would allow me to do this, all that I've found want to strictly convert a cloud to a mesh, no adding or deleting vertices.

I should note that I'm still more or less a beginning with PCL, especially with respect to meshes and surfaces.  So perhaps this isn't even a good approach and I should stick to voxels?  Open to ideas.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no incremental meshing solution at this point. Is your ground point cloud planar? Then the problem is much simpler than general surface reconstruction.

Comment: Not really, sometimes my ground is on hill, sometimes objects will shadow regions which will leave holes in my cloud, there could be slopes, etc.. I have no a priory model of the ground, all I can do is apply constraints (discount certain steep gradients, ignore points X m above etc.)

Comment: So what assumptions do you make when separating the ground from the rest? Could you express the ground as a height field?

Comment: For the ground separation it self, PCL's ProgressiveMorphologicalFilter uses a windowing algorithm where it searches for ground planes at decreasing scales.  So it throws out points with sharp Z gradients, or points that are high above what it thinks is the ground, etc. The filter output is a vector of indices of the points it considers to be part of the ground.  So my desire for a surface/mesh would be the same as a height field, or in other words, a defined height value at every (x,y) coordinate.  Right now, my ground cloud is potentially sparse and irregular.

Comment: So could you express the ground border as a 2D alpha shape and triangulate that including the sample points with e.g. Delaunay? Then, adding new points is just a matter of updating the alpha shape and the triangulation, which is a very local operation. You might also want to split triangles that are too large and interpolate the height in a reasonable way.

Comment: One issue is that my point source, a LIDAR, is often mounted on a car or airplane, so I don't have a good idea of the extent of my ground plane.  In some trials, the plane flies from land to an island several km away (and the lidar range is only ~2km.)  So I can't define an a priori alpha shape, this is why I was hoping to be able to build on to the mesh on the edges to allow it to grow.  As for the method of triangulation, Delaunay or any other is great, but I was hoping to find PCL functions or something that someone's already written. :)

Comment: I don't think that there is some ready-to-use solution. You could define the alpha based on local point density. In the end, you end up deleting triangles from the Delaunay graph. And which triangles to delete can be determined by any other criterion (e.g. triangle area).